# Start Gnome-Application from SSH-Shell

Tags: linux, shell, gnome

my development server has a running Gnome-Desktop. I am connected to it by a ssh session. The Gnome-Session and the ssh session are running with the same user.

How to I start a Gnome-application (for example gedit) from the ssh remote session so that it appears on the remote servers Gnome-Desktop?

Thanks a lot,
Hacksteak25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would probably work:

Tcsh:

```
setenv DISPLAY :0
gedit
```

Bash:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
gedit
```

If you are not the user that is logged into the Gnome session, then you would need to do `xhost +` to disable the authentication.

If the above doesn't work, then instead of `:0`, try simply copying the DISPLAY environment variable to the ssh terminal.

Comment: Some programs that use DBUS may not work correctly. I tried this with banshee and it segfaulted when it could not resolve a .service with the display manager.

Answer (score 1):

To support DBUS messaging, use:

```
ssh -Y remoteuser@remotehost dbus-launch -f gedit
```

The "-f" option starts the remote GUI application on the local desktop and returns, leaving the local terminal available for the next command.